# Recursive method that takes an input s and k and generates all the strings of length k

Tags: java, recursion

I need to write a recursive method that takes an input s and k and generates all the strings of length k that satisfy the property that no two consecutive places hold the same symbol. The integers 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 represent the symbols.

For example, when s = 4 and k = 3 and the alphabet chosen is {1, 2, 3, 4}, the number of strings is 36 and the strings are:
121, 123, 124, 131, 132, 134, 141, 142, 143, 212, 213, 214, 231, 232, 234, 241, 242, 243, 312, 313, 314, 321, 323, 324, 341, 342, 343, 412, 413, 414, 421, 423, 424, 431, 432, 434.

I don't need to print all the strings, I just have to generate them to be able to count the total and put it into a table.

For my code so far:

```
public static int generateNum(int k, int s){

    if (k==1){
        return s;
    }
    if (s==1 && k>1){
        return 0;
    }
}
```

I am still learning recursion and I'm not sure how to tackle this problem! Any help would be great.

Comment: I rewrote the answer below, with code.

Answer (score 0):

The important part of this question is to understand how recursion helps you solve it. If you're learning it for the first time, it's helpful to visualize the end case first, and then understand "how you got there" by introducing an earlier step.
In this case, the end case is simple - You're on your last count, basically asking how many 1-character words can be done using an alphabet of S characters - so you return a list of S 1-letter words.
The previous step you're asked how many 2-letter words can be found in an S+1 alphabet. You create a list of S+1 prefixes for each character available in your alphabet, and use the recursion to get you all the suffices for each word.

So it might be something like this pseudo code:
k - the number of digits in the product - 2
s - the available digits to choose from - {1,2,3}

go over each letter in the alphabet {1,2,3}:

prefix "1" appended with (recursion call - generate k-1=1 letter words from {2,3}):
    "2"
    "3"
create a list of the prefix and all suffices provided by recursion ("12", "13"), add to list

prefix "2" appended with (recursion call - generate k-1=1 letter words from {1,3}):
    "1"
    "3"
create a list of the prefix and all suffices provided by recursion ("21", "23"), add to list

prefix "3" appended with (recursion call - generate k-1=1 letter words from {1,2}):
    "1"
    "2"
create a list of the prefix and all suffices provided by recursion ("31", "32"), add to list

pack a list of all words received and return them: ("12", "13", "21", "23", "31", "32")

Now, if you look at the k=2 step, you see you got a list of 6 strings - which could be added into a table, or used as suffices to send back to a call function k=3 with alphabet {1,2,3,4}...

To put it in Java Code:

```
  // This is the recursive method you want
  public static List<String> getNumbersWithNoConsequetiveDigits 
    (List<Character> digits, int numOfDigits, Character doNotUse) {

    List<String> numbersList = new ArrayList<String>();

    // Best practice in recursion - handle empty end-cases first.
    if (CollectionUtils.isEmpty(digits))
      return numbersList;
    if (numOfDigits == 0)
      return numbersList;

    // End case - 1 digit remains. Return the only word possible.
    if (digits.size() == 1) {
      numbersList.add("" + digits.get(0));
      return numbersList;
    }

    // end case: return all 1 digit words from a n-size alphabet.
    if (numOfDigits == 1) {
      for (Character digit : digits) {
        if (!digit.equals(doNotUse)) {
          numbersList.add("" + digit);
        }
      }
      return numbersList;
    }

    // recursion itself
    for (Character digit : digits) {

      // Skip the do-not-use digits
      if (digit.equals(doNotUse))
        continue;
      String prefix = "" + digit;
      List<String> remainingNumbers = getNumbersWithNoConsequetiveDigits 
        (digits, numOfDigits - 1, digit);
      for (String number : remainingNumbers) {
        numbersList.add(prefix + number);
      }
    }
    return numbersList;
  }

  // Test it in the main, with your example
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<Character> digits = new ArrayList<Character>();
    digits.add('1');
    digits.add('2');
    digits.add('3');
    digits.add('4');
    List<String> numbers = getNumbersWithNoConsequetiveDigits(digits, 3, null);
    for (String number : numbers) {
      System.out.println(number);
    }
  }
```

Output is:

```
121
123
124
131
132
134
141
142
143
212
213
214
231
232
234
241
242
243
312
313
314
321
323
324
341
342
343
412
413
414
421
423
424
431
432
434
```

Answer (score 0):

**if you just need the total number**:

For any k > 0 and s > 0, you can directly return the answer s*Math.pow(s-1,k-1); otherwise return 0.

**if you need to get the strings**:

Let's say we will save the generated strings into an ArrayList, here's the code:

```
public static int generateNum(int k, int s) {
    List<String> resultList = new ArrayList<>();
    processRecursion(resultList, "", s, k);
    return resultList.size();
}

private static void processRecursion(List<String> list, String finishedStr, int s, int unfinishedCount) {
    if (unfinishedCount == 0 && !finishedStr.isEmpty()) {
        list.add(finishedStr);
        return;
    }

    for (int i = 1; i <= s; i++) {
        if (!finishedStr.isEmpty() && finishedStr.codePointAt(finishedStr.length()-1) == 0x30 + i) {
            continue;
        }
        processRecursion(list, finishedStr + i, s, unfinishedCount - 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Directly returning the answer s*Math.pow(s-1,k-1) would not be recursive tho?

Comment: No, it's not necessary.